# Pattern not providing expected output

Tags: java, regex

I have the following code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d*\\s*[-\\+\\*/\\$£]");

String input = "3 3 * 4 + 2 /";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    output.add(matcher.group());
}


for(String s : output){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

I would very much like the output in my list to be the following:

```
3 3 *
4 +
2 /
```

Alas my actual output is:

```
3 *
4 +
2 /
```

I am sure there is a regex wizard out there who can show me the issue :)

Comment: because the first 3 isn't followed by a non-word character.

Comment: there is a space between 3 and 3

Comment: But it's expecting `[-+*/$£]`.

Comment: Thankyou for the comments, seems i need to re engineer my regex

Comment: Do you have to parse something like: `3 4 + 4 5 + *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is a space exists between two digits, you need to add a pattern to match also the second digit and make it as optional. And also i suggest you to use `\d+` instead of `\d*` because `\d*` matches also an empty string.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+(\\s\\d+)?\\s*[-+*/$£]");

String input = "3 3 * 4 + 2 /";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    output.add(matcher.group());
}


for(String s : output){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Output:

```
3 3 *
4 +
2 /
```

Comment: Another question if i may if i had an input of 3 3 3 * 4 + 2 / how would i get an output of 3 3 3 * instead of 3 3 * 

i apologise but regex has never been my fortay.

Comment: essentially there can be any number of digits between operators

Comment: change `?` to `*` in the above regex like `"\\d+(\\s\\d+)*\\s*[-\\+\\*/\\$£]"`

Comment: Another thing is, I doubt this answer can parse `3 4 + 4 5 + *`, which is a valid postfix notation.

Comment: i also note that it cannot parse 3.0 4.0 + 4.5 5.5 + * so i need to make a change for that too. But this is my fault for not providing a scenario that covers all eventualities